# DIV layout not rendering with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and was trying my hands on 12 column layout. Looking at the tutorials it should just happen out of box, but for some reason the Divs are stacking one below another rather than arranging themselves in row layout with spans. Its baffling can someone help?

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6">Text 123456</div>
        <div class="span6">Text 123456</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is is the fiddle - I am using Chrome and Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/vshtmczf/

Comment: You're using Bootstrap 2 classes but in your external resources you're linking Bootstrap v3.2. You can find the documentation for v3.2 grid system [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: @koala_dev Thanks. It didnt strike me that there could be breaking changes between ver2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to got parent element with class container and instead of span6 use col-xs-6, because you are using Bootstrap 3.2. [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

look here:

```
<body class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">Text 123456</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">Text 123456</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vshtmczf/1/)